# Finding the exponents of a multiple power law: is linear regression valid?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear-model, power-law

I want to fit a multiple power law equation of the form

$y = {x_1}^{\alpha_1} {x_2}^{\alpha_2}$

where I have many examples of $y, x_1, x_2$. (Note there is no intercept.)

Is it possible for me to transform this into

$\log y = \alpha_1 \log x_1 + \alpha_2 \log x_2$

and fit with a standard linear regression (without an intercept)?

Will this lead to biased values of $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$? Is it better to do something like an MLE estimate via numerical optimization?

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data?

Comment: @JamesPhillips My data are actually more complicated than this situation - I am only asking for a general understanding. If you want I could fake up some data though.

Comment: Please fake up some data, and add to the post (as an edit)